# The Civic Duty badge description in the queue statistic doesn't fit the modal window on Russian Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, user-interface, localization, russian-stackoverflow

> [image]

Probably, the problem could be also on other localized sites.

Comment: @Shog9 much better is to talk to the design team about how to build an interface sensitive to the content.

Comment: @Shog9 Average word length: english - 5,2 letters, russian - 7,2

Comment: Heh... I suppose that might be slightly less work than altering a major language @alexolut

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, the Armenians will never have a chance to get their localized SO (civic duty  քաղաքացիական պարտքը), as well as the Finns (kansalaisvelvollisuus), the Greeks (πολιτικό καθήκον), the Danes (borgerlige pligter), the Turks (vatandaşlık görevi) and many other longword languages.

Comment: @Shog9 Actually, UI with pixel alignment is guaranteed to break no matter what languages you start with and translate into. No matter how hard you try, localized text will get longer than it should statistically just because translating is hard, even if statistics actually apply to a specific case, which almost never happens. So even if you start with Russian and translate into English, you'll face exactly the same problems.

Comment: I hope that as the modern HTML/CSS technologies spread and evolve (CSS Grid in particular), developers will no longer have an excuse to use pixel alignment — just like space alignement is mocked in Word documents, so should pixel alignment in Web UI.

Comment: Oh, for sure @athari; this particular bit of UI is about 6 years old - it predates not just grid/flow layouts but also pretty much all localization work. We can probably do a much better job now.